# Text on the image with css and html only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add different texts on the center of images. Seems like I'm unable to do this and will need some help with the task.

So, I have 4 images on the page. Now I want to put text on the images. What I have so far are 4 images on page but the text is not appear properly. Here is the part of the html

```css
.images {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
  width: 430px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#img-row {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
#img-row:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.class {
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
button.button {
  width: 570px;
  margin-left: 182px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.caption-text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-row">
  <a href="">
    <button class="button">
      Button
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="img-row">

  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>

</div>
<div id="img-row">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like so far: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ew5oucdf/). Text appears only two times.

Comment: your text goes over the whole width for both images in a row. you have your text twice, but it is on the same position so you only see one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have nested your images within an `a` tag, then the text was aligning `left:0` of `img-row`. Now it correctly aligns with the image because I added:

```
#img-row > a {
  position: relative;
}
```

Consider the following example:

```css
#a2{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="a1"><p>hello1</p></a>
<a id="a2"><p>hello2</p></a>
```

> `absolute` behaves like `fixed` except relative to the *nearest positioned ancestor instead of relative* to the viewport. If an absolutely-positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body... http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Your working example:

```css
.images {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
  width: 430px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#img-row {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
#img-row > a {
  position: relative;
}
#img-row:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.class {
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
button.button {
  width: 570px;
  margin-left: 182px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.caption-text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-row">
  <a href="">
    <button class="button">
      Button
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="img-row">

  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>

</div>
<div id="img-row">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" class="images" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">This is a caption text</figcaption>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats perfect.

Comment: @VLS You were so close!

Comment: it's always like this. Something very small always missing.. Thank's again. Can accept answer in 1min